# how to get two values from MAX() aggregation function in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Now i have a query that i'll use the MAX() aggregation function on it . 
i made it

`WITH t2 AS(
        SELECT customerid , sum(total) sumTotal
        FROM invoice
        GROUP BY 1
        ORDER BY 1
)
SELECT c.customerid customerid ,  c.firstName firstName , c.lastName lastName ,
         c.country customerCountry , MAX(sumTotal) MaxSumTotal
FROM customer c JOIN t2
ON c.customerid = t2.customerid
GROUP BY 4
ORDER BY 4`

but that one return only one valuse for MAX() . 
i have one of them have two equal MAX() output . 
i want to show both of them

how i can do that ???

that is the ERD diagram for the database
[image: Database ERD]

Comment: Your query seems invalid. t2 results in one row per customer. You join this with the customer table, so that's still one row per customer. Then you group by country so as to get one row per country. How then can you still select customer ID and name? I doubt there is just one customer per country. It doesn't sound at all like PostgreSQL to let this slip.

Answer (score 3):

Use `rank()`:

```
WITH t2 AS (
      SELECT customerid , sum(total) as sumTotal,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum(total) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM invoice
      GROUP BY 1
     )
SELECT c.customerid, c.firstName firstName, c.lastName lastName,
       c.country as customerCountry, sumTotal as MaxSumTotal
FROM customer c JOIN
     t2
     ON c.customerid = t2.customerid
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY c.customerid;
```

Comment: i tried it but iget that error
" near "(": syntax error "
at the rank () braces

Comment: @BassamAbdeltwab . . . There is nothing obviously wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You may search for `rank()` to rank the customers by their total revenue (or whatever that is) and limit the result to thos with a rank of 1, i.e. the maximum total.

```
SELECT y.customerid,
       y.firstname,
       y.lastname,
       y.country,
       y.total
       FROM (SELECT c.customerid,
                    c.firstname,
                    c.lastname,
                    c.country,
                    x.total,
                    rank() OVER (ORDER BY x.total DESC) r
                    FROM customer c
                         INNER JOIN (SELECT i.customerid,
                                            sum(i.total) total
                                            FROM invoice i
                                            GROUP BY i.customerid) x
                                    ON x.customerid = c.customerid) y
       WHERE y.r = 1;
```

Comment: i tried it but iget that error " near "(": syntax error " at the rank () braces

Comment: I cannot reproduce a syntax error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=d7982e2a56ffdd67562f7258198488fd

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with the below code :

`WITH t1 as (
        SELECT (customer.customerid) customerid , firstName , lastName , country ,
                SUM(invoice.total) totalSpent 
        FROM customer JOIN invoice
        ON customer.customerid = invoice.customerid
        GROUP BY customer.customerid
)
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1 JOIN(
        SELECT customerid , firstName , lastName , country , MAX(totalSpent) as MaxTotalSpent
        FROM t1
        GROUP BY country
)t2
ON t2.country = t1.country
WHERE t1.totalSpent = t2.MaxTotalSpent
ORDER BY country`